# How do front end developers create web templates to either sell or show their talents?

Tags: html, templates

I am new to web design/web development, I have been learning on/off over the past year or so and believe I do have a good basic grasp on HTML, CSS and using text editors etc.

What I struggle to find or understand:
How do you devs create templates of websites without using a CMS ?

Do you just create HTML and CSS files and then somehow show them on the web, or do you have to use certain software to create the templates?

Comment: I suggest you to look on Google "How to create a web template" or some similar terms. The first result I found is a [detailed video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyeubYQxHyY) on how to make a simple template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are just HTML, CSS and Javascript files.

If you have a CMS as the backend of the website, you can integrate a template to your CMS however this is usually a manual process. However it's very important to note that a template and a CMS are two totally different things.

If you have any issued using a template with a specific CMS then feel free to post specific examples.

Comment: Thanks for this TidyDev. If i was not to use a CMS how else could you showcase your templates?